# What is the alternate for XmlDumper class in Drools 8?

Tags: drools

What is the alternate for XmlDumper class in Drools 8? After migrating from `Drools 7.45.0.Final` to `Drools 8.43.0.Final`, we have broken reference for XmlDumper class.

Tried to find alternative in the docs but there is no mention of the same in drools 8 documentation.
We want to convert Drl files to XML files but now our program is broken due to Drools 8 upgrade.

Comment: Looks like it was removed in 8.22